# KDE first steps: dolphin build fails, gpgme fails 'undefined reference to `qt_version_tag@Qt_5.12''

Tags: kde-plasma

I am following the 'getting started' guide to building KDE, here:
https://community.kde.org/Get_Involved/development#Build_some_software
The environment is a pristine and updated KDE Neon VM.

All goes well until the step 3.1:

```
kdesrc-build dolphin --include-dependencies
```

It fails:

```
libtool: link: g++ -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-shadow -o t-keylist t-keylist.o t-support.o -Wl,--disable-new-dtags  ../../cpp/src/.libs/libgpgmepp.so ../src/.libs/libqgpgme.so ../../../src/.libs/libgpgme.so -L/home/tim/kde/qt5/lib -L/home/tim/kde/usr/lib /home/tim/kde/usr/lib/libgpg-error.so /home/tim/kde/qt5/lib/libQt5Test.so /home/tim/kde/qt5/lib/libQt5Core.so -lstdc++ -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/tim/kde/build/gpgme/lang/cpp/src/.libs -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/tim/kde/build/gpgme/lang/qt/src/.libs -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/tim/kde/build/gpgme/src/.libs -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/tim/kde/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/tim/kde/qt5/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/tim/kde/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/home/tim/kde/qt5/lib
../src/.libs/libqgpgme.so: undefined reference to `qt_version_tag@Qt_5.12'
```

The implication is I think that I have the wrong version of qt, yet I followed the instructions carefully.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert with KDE I just try to follow the getting started to build plasma mobile and I had the same error.

To solve the problem I first updated kdesrc-build

```
cd ~/kde/src/kdesrc-build
git pull
```

Then I changed the Qt version to 5.12 in file qt5-build-include in folder kdesrc-build.
Update the Qt source code.

```
cd ~/kde/src/Qt5
git pull
```

After I needed to remove the build folder of Qt.
And build again.

And voila!!

Comment: for me, I get this:

Error updating gpgme, removing from list of packages to build.
 > Unable to perform git fetch for origin (git://git.gnupg.org/gpgme.git)

the git repository is a 404

Comment: Do you still get that error? I can clone that repository just fine.

Comment: My problems were fixed by https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=411419 (Neon upgrade of Qt library). I can now compile all three test scenarios in the tutorial: dolphin, kio and plasma.